# How to use "Omniture Dashboard" to analyse the tracked data from ios app?

Tags: ios, adobe-analytics

I had used "AdobeMobileLibrary" from omniture to track states and events by using the method "tractAction".Debugger Log shows that tracking successful. But i want to know "How to see that "trackAction" data in omniture dashboard ? If i login into omniture dashboard there are so many options like "Site catalyst, Analytics, Reports",etc. Can any one of you help, How and where(Under which option in dashboard) i have to see the track Action in omniture dashboard ?

I had used following code

```
[ADBMobile trackAction:events data:nil];
[ADBMobile trackAction:pageName data:contextData];
```

Advance thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issue right now.  The debugger provided by Adobe indicates that I am sending off metadata properly and for the correct events & eVars.

I cannot see any of it being logged in the dashboard.  If I find my solution, I'll update this post with it in hopes it may help someone else.

Edit:

> I did eventually figure out what the issue was.  The pressing issue is
>   that the report suite that I was using had "Timestamps required"
>   meaning the system didn't generate their timestamp, but instead
>   expected you to send it with the events.
>
> This can be done on the Adobe Marketing Cloud / Admin / Report Suites
>   page.  From that page, choose your report suite ID and then click
>   "Edit Settings".  Under the "General" tab in the settings should be
>   the option for "Timestamp configuration".
>
> I've set mine to optional, and it appears to work.

Comment: I did eventually figure out what the issue was.  The pressing issue is that the report suite that I was using had "Timestamps required" meaning the system didn't generate their timestamp, but instead expected you to send it with the events.

Comment: Thanks, i will try this solution